# passing a variable in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am just beginning to learn PHP ( I have some moderate Java exp)

but I cant figure out how to simply pass a variable as an argument.

Please see below from tinkering with the underground api. I create the variable for the URL I need to pass but when I put it in the second line it doesnt seem to read the variable. url is the variable in question.  When i place the url directly as the argument then it works without issue. However the below code gives an error.

```
  <?php
     $url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/19115";
      $json_string = file_get_contents($url);
      $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
      $location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
      $temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'};
      echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";
    ?>
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$location in D:\Dev\xampp\htdocs\welcome.php on line 6

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Dev\xampp\htdocs\welcome.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$current_observation in D:\Dev\xampp\htdocs\welcome.php on line 7

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Dev\xampp\htdocs\welcome.php on line 7
Current temperature in is:
```

JSON response when using URL in browser:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "geolookup": 1
  ,
  "conditions": 1
  }
    }
        ,   "location": {
        "type":"CITY",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "country_name":"USA",
        "state":"PA",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "tz_short":"EDT",
        "tz_long":"America/New_York",
        "lat":"40.09180450",
        "lon":"-75.04257202",
        "zip":"19115",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"99999",
        "l":"/q/zmw:19115.1.99999",
        "requesturl":"US/PA/Philadelphia.html",
        "wuiurl":"http://www.wunderground.com/US/PA/Philadelphia.html",
        "nearby_weather_stations": {
        "airport": {
        "station": [
        { "city":"Northeast Philadelphia", "state":"PA", "country":"US", "icao":"KPNE", "lat":"40.07889938", "lon":"-75.01335144" }
        ,{ "city":"Philadelphia Wings Airport", "state":"PA", "country":"US", "icao":"KLOM", "lat":"40.13755417", "lon":"-75.26513672" }
        ,{ "city":"Mount Holly", "state":"NJ", "country":"US", "icao":"KVAY", "lat":"39.94076157", "lon":"-74.84071350" }
        ,{ "city":"Doylestown", "state":"PA", "country":"US", "icao":"KDYL", "lat":"40.33015823", "lon":"-75.12286377" }
        ]
        }
        ,
        "pws": {
        "station": [
        {
        "neighborhood":"Beth Ayres/High Road",
        "city":"Huntingdon Valley",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAHUNTI3",
        "lat":40.115807,
        "lon":-75.053764,
        "distance_km":2,
        "distance_mi":1
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Grant and Academy",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA26",
        "lat":40.069057,
        "lon":-75.006996,
        "distance_km":3,
        "distance_mi":2
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Bryn Athyn",
        "city":"Huntingdon Valley",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAHUNTI4",
        "lat":40.133362,
        "lon":-75.060265,
        "distance_km":4,
        "distance_mi":2
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Rydal",
        "city":"Jenkintown",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAJENKI3",
        "lat":40.098648,
        "lon":-75.100975,
        "distance_km":5,
        "distance_mi":3
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Philadelphia",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA37",
        "lat":40.126778,
        "lon":-74.996559,
        "distance_km":5,
        "distance_mi":3
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Chalfont",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA45",
        "lat":40.076885,
        "lon":-74.977242,
        "distance_km":5,
        "distance_mi":3
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Elkin\u0027s Park - Logan\u0027s Alley",
        "city":"Jenkintown",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAJENKI4",
        "lat":40.085697,
        "lon":-75.126213,
        "distance_km":7,
        "distance_mi":4
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Willow Grove Weather Center",
        "city":"Willow Grove",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAWILLO7",
        "lat":40.142101,
        "lon":-75.106400,
        "distance_km":7,
        "distance_mi":4
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"NOS_PORTS Tacony-Palmyra Bridge, NJ",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"MTPBN4",
        "lat":40.011940,
        "lon":-75.042999,
        "distance_km":8,
        "distance_mi":5
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Cinnaminson Street",
        "city":"Riverton",
        "state":"NJ",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KNJRIVER2",
        "lat":40.010277,
        "lon":-75.010132,
        "distance_km":9,
        "distance_mi":5
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Fitzwatertown",
        "city":"Willow Grove",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAWILLO10",
        "lat":40.149128,
        "lon":-75.129265,
        "distance_km":9,
        "distance_mi":5
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Dresher Pa",
        "city":"Dresher",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPADRESH3",
        "lat":40.138088,
        "lon":-75.150169,
        "distance_km":10,
        "distance_mi":6
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"",
        "city":"Palmyra",
        "state":"NJ",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KNJPALMY4",
        "lat":40.000000,
        "lon":-75.010002,
        "distance_km":10,
        "distance_mi":6
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"North Hills",
        "city":"North Hills",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPANORTH5",
        "lat":40.116211,
        "lon":-75.165329,
        "distance_km":10,
        "distance_mi":6
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"",
        "city":"Cinnaminson",
        "state":"NJ",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KNJCINNA2",
        "lat":39.997898,
        "lon":-75.008797,
        "distance_km":10,
        "distance_mi":6
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Croydon",
        "city":"Croydon",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPACROYD1",
        "lat":40.087749,
        "lon":-74.903839,
        "distance_km":11,
        "distance_mi":7
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Delran-Millside Heights",
        "city":"Delran",
        "state":"NJ",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KNJDELRA2",
        "lat":40.008129,
        "lon":-74.955276,
        "distance_km":11,
        "distance_mi":7
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"oreland",
        "city":"Oreland",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAORELA2",
        "lat":40.119926,
        "lon":-75.177963,
        "distance_km":11,
        "distance_mi":7
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Weather Genius @ Old Wyndmoor",
        "city":"Wyndmoor",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAWYNDM3",
        "lat":40.078907,
        "lon":-75.192093,
        "distance_km":12,
        "distance_mi":7
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"CWOP# AR939",
        "city":"Penndel",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPENND1",
        "lat":40.156097,
        "lon":-74.917603,
        "distance_km":12,
        "distance_mi":7
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Downtown Fort Washington",
        "city":"Fort Washington",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAFORTW5",
        "lat":40.147438,
        "lon":-75.179253,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":7
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Church Rd, Cinnaminson",
        "city":"Cinnaminson",
        "state":"NJ",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KNJCINNA1",
        "lat":39.979568,
        "lon":-74.991234,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":7
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"West Mount Airy",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA32",
        "lat":40.058418,
        "lon":-75.192741,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":7
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Mount Airy",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA54",
        "lat":40.054298,
        "lon":-75.191826,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"HorshamWeather.Com",
        "city":"Horsham",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAHORSH1",
        "lat":40.192310,
        "lon":-75.129883,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Maple Glen",
        "city":"Maple Glen",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAMAPLE4",
        "lat":40.162884,
        "lon":-75.170181,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Germantown",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA39",
        "lat":40.023037,
        "lon":-75.173729,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Port Richmond (JcWeather)",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA4",
        "lat":39.980930,
        "lon":-75.112869,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Germantown Ave. Chestnut Hill",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA11",
        "lat":40.071766,
        "lon":-75.201759,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Jenks Academy-Chestnut Hill",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAPHILA53",
        "lat":40.074879,
        "lon":-75.203316,
        "distance_km":13,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Erdenheim",
        "city":"Erdenheim",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAERDEN1",
        "lat":40.089100,
        "lon":-75.211998,
        "distance_km":14,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"",
        "city":"Richboro",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPARICHB2",
        "lat":40.221783,
        "lon":-75.021301,
        "distance_km":14,
        "distance_mi":8
        },
        {
        "neighborhood":"Ivyland, PA",
        "city":"Warminster",
        "state":"PA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KPAWARMI4",
        "lat":40.222992,
        "lon":-75.049301,
        "distance_km":14,
        "distance_mi":8
        }
        ]
        }
        }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"Philadelphia, PA",
        "city":"Philadelphia",
        "state":"PA",
        "state_name":"Pennsylvania",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "zip":"19115",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"99999",
        "latitude":"40.09180450",
        "longitude":"-75.04257202",
        "elevation":"46.00000000"
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"Beth Ayres/High Road, Huntingdon Valley, Pennsylvania",
        "city":"Beth Ayres/High Road, Huntingdon Valley",
        "state":"Pennsylvania",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "latitude":"40.115807",
        "longitude":"-75.053764",
        "elevation":"250 ft"
        },
        "estimated": {
        },
        "station_id":"KPAHUNTI3",
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on September 18, 6:04 PM EDT",
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Thu, 18 Sep 2014 18:04:46 -0400",
        "observation_epoch":"1411077886",
        "local_time_rfc822":"Thu, 18 Sep 2014 18:04:53 -0400",
        "local_epoch":"1411077893",
        "local_tz_short":"EDT",
        "local_tz_long":"America/New_York",
        "local_tz_offset":"-0400",
        "weather":"Clear",
        "temperature_string":"71.0 F (21.7 C)",
        "temp_f":71.0,
        "temp_c":21.7,
        "relative_humidity":"66%",
        "wind_string":"Calm",
        "wind_dir":"SSW",
        "wind_degrees":207,
        "wind_mph":0.0,
        "wind_gust_mph":0,
        "wind_kph":0,
        "wind_gust_kph":0,
        "pressure_mb":"1016",
        "pressure_in":"30.01",
        "pressure_trend":"0",
        "dewpoint_string":"59 F (15 C)",
        "dewpoint_f":59,
        "dewpoint_c":15,
        "heat_index_string":"NA",
        "heat_index_f":"NA",
        "heat_index_c":"NA",
        "windchill_string":"NA",
        "windchill_f":"NA",
        "windchill_c":"NA",
        "feelslike_string":"71.0 F (21.7 C)",
        "feelslike_f":"71.0",
        "feelslike_c":"21.7",
        "visibility_mi":"10.0",
        "visibility_km":"16.1",
        "solarradiation":"--",
        "UV":"1","precip_1hr_string":"0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
        "precip_1hr_in":"0.00",
        "precip_1hr_metric":" 0",
        "precip_today_string":"0.00 in (0 mm)",
        "precip_today_in":"0.00",
        "precip_today_metric":"0",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/US/PA/Philadelphia.html",
        "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KPAHUNTI3",
        "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=40.115807,-75.053764",
        "nowcast":""
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your file using a .php extension?

Comment: Look at the JSON coming back, it doesn't contain the values you're trying to read. When I load that URL I get `{ "response": { "version":"0.1", "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html", "features": { } , "error": { "type": "keynotfound" ,"description": "this key does not exist" } } }` There is no "location" or anything, hence your error. Looks like they want a key for authentication and you aren't supplying one.

Comment: @SterlingArcher   Yes it is. Definitely seems like its not getting the variable though.

Comment: @benpix you are getting that because i didnt give you my real key for the api.

Comment: Can you provide the data you actually get back? Then we can check you're trying to read the variables right.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem with output.

If I use your code and in `$json_string` I put JSON string you provided for the following code (the same as yours):

```
$json_string = 'Here is the JSON string you provided';
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
$temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'};
echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";
```

I get output:

> Current temperature in Philadelphia is: 71

Of course I would use for it simpler notation:

```
$json_string = 'Here is the JSON string you provided';
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->location->city;
$temp_f = $parsed_json->current_observation->temp_f;
echo "Current temperature in {$location} is: {$temp_f}\n";
```

But it will give me exact same result:

> Current temperature in Philadelphia is: 71

I've tested it in PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.5 and in both versions the code is working without any problem, so it might be possible that you don't always get the result you provided from API.

So you should check if result of json_decode is not null:

```
$json_string = 'Not valid JSON string';
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
if (!is_null($parsed_json)) {
    $location = $parsed_json->location->city;
    $temp_f = $parsed_json->current_observation->temp_f;
    echo "Current temperature in {$location} is: {$temp_f}\n";
}
else {
    echo "JSON cannot be encoded";
}
```

and if I run this code without a change I get:

> JSON cannot be encoded

Comment: in code there are a extra `'` character. `city'` should change as `city`

Comment: You cant use the URL I provided because its not the real API key. I will update which response from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

instead of KEY you need to put your API Key and then the following code will work I promise:

```
$url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json";
$json_string = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);

if (isset($parsed_json['response']['error']) {
    die('error occured');
}

$location = $data['current_observation']['display_location']['city'];
$temp_f = $data['current_observation']['temp_f'];
echo "Current temperature in $location is: $temp_f\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer:

```
<?php
 $url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/19115.json";
  $json_string = file_get_contents($url);
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
  $location = $parsed_json->location->city;
  $temp_f = $parsed_json->current_observation->temp_f;
  echo "Current temperature in {$location} is: {$temp_f}\n";
?>
```

Comment: This is exactly I wrote in my answer but your method also should work. Please look at my edited answer